# Exchanging demonetized Indian Rupee notes in Singapore

Tags: india, exchange

India had [demonetized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2016_Indian_banknote_demonetisation) old notes of 500 and 1000 denomination back in November. The deadline for depositing old notes in banks was December 30, 2016.

Recently we saw we still have quite a bit of demonetized 500 and 1000 rupees notes. Is it possible to get them exchanged in Singapore?

Comment: Why would you think a bank outside India would take money that banks inside India no longer take?

Comment: As the bank-notes are no longer legal tender [or even backed by the central bank](http://www.prsindia.org/billtrack/-the-specified-bank-notes-cessation-of-liabilities-ordinance-2016-4536/), it is highly unlikely you'll find anyone in Singapore willing to swap them legally.

Comment: I am flagging this question as off-topic as this isn't about travelling per se. OP is (most probably) resident in Singapore and wants to exchange left-over Indian currency while still there.

Comment: off-topic as this isn't about travelling per se. OP is (most probably) resident in Singapore and wants to exchange left-over Indian currency while living there

Comment: @RoryAlsop Dealing with left-over currency is a part of travelling.

Answer (score 2):

There are branches of some major Indian banks in Singapore, try going there and talk to the manager/staff about this issue. They might be able to help or give you some information.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can't. Anyway , the Indian Government gave relaxation to people who are not in india for that period. If you are on of them, then you can change the money in selected branches of RBI (you have to come to india). But you should provide the passport as a proof that you are not visited here in that period(Nov 8 to Dec 30).